# How can i load csv file data in BigQuery using bq load command?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, bq-load

I have created multiple tables into BigQuery dataset and also i have so many csv files stored into GCS and now i want to load csv files data into each tables. i have used below command to laod data from csv file into table. Table contains more 300+ columns.

```
bq load ARADMIN.T1851 gs://new007/t1851data.csv C1:STRING,C2:STRING,C3:NUMERIC,C4:STRING,C5:STRING,C6:NUMERIC,C7:NUMERIC,C8:STRING,C112:STRING,C179:STRING,C60900:STRING,C3004100:STRING,C10000001:STRING,C10003001:NUMERIC,C200000003:STRING,C200000004:STRING,C200000005:STRING,C200000006:STRING,C200000007:STRING,C200000012:STRING,C230000009:STRING,C240001002:STRING,C240001003:STRING,C240001005:STRING,C250000023:NUMERIC,C260000001:STRING,C300270800:STRING,C300270900:STRING,C300271000:STRING,C300271200:STRING,C300617700:STRING,C301090500:STRING,C301284400:STRING,C301290300:NUMERIC,C301321300:STRING,C301368700:STRING,C301389272:STRING,C301390090:NUMERIC,C301391782:STRING,C301412900:NUMERIC,C301540300:STRING,C301541000:STRING,C301541600:STRING,C301541700:NUMERIC,C301550900:NUMERIC,C301571900:STRING,C301572000:STRING,C301572100:STRING,C301572200:STRING,C301600300:STRING,C301610100:STRING,C301612200:STRING,C301626500:NUMERIC,C301629100:STRING,C301667500:NUMERIC,C301674600:NUMERIC,C301734000:STRING,C301735100:STRING,C301736700:STRING,C301788500:STRING,C301807600:STRING,C301809900:STRING,C301810000:STRING,C301827100:STRING,C301827300:STRING,C301920700:STRING,C301920800:STRING,C301920900:STRING,C301921000:STRING,C301921100:STRING,C301921200:STRING,C301921300:STRING,C301921400:STRING,C301921500:STRING,C301921600:STRING,C301921700:STRING,C301921800:STRING,C301921900:STRING,C303070100:NUMERIC,C303070200:NUMERIC,C303356300:STRING,C303497300:STRING,C303497400:STRING,C303497500:STRING,C303519300:STRING,C303522900:STRING,C303523900:STRING,C303544200:STRING,C303544300:STRING,C303558600:STRING,C303595900:NUMERIC,C303601600:STRING,C303601700:STRING,C303616500:STRING,C303720800:NUMERIC,C303755200:STRING,C303758300:STRING,C303790700:STRING,C1000000000:STRING,C1000000001:STRING,C1000000002:STRING,C1000000003:STRING,C1000000004:STRING,C1000000010:STRING,C1000000014:STRING,C1000000017:STRING,C1000000018:STRING,C1000000019:STRING,C1000000020:STRING,C1000000022:NUMERIC,C1000000026:NUMERIC,C1000000027:NUMERIC,C1000000028:STRING,C1000000029:STRING,C1000000030:STRING,C1000000031:STRING,C1000000035:STRING,C1000000036:STRING,C1000000037:STRING,C1000000039:STRING,C1000000046:STRING,C1000000048:STRING,C1000000054:STRING,C1000000056:STRING,C1000000063:STRING,C1000000064:STRING,C1000000065:STRING,C1000000069:STRING,C1000000074:STRING,C1000000079:STRING,C1000000080:STRING,C1000000082:STRING,C1000000099:NUMERIC,C1000000109:STRING,C1000000118:NUMERIC,C1000000145:STRING,C1000000150:NUMERIC,C1000000151:STRING,C1000000156:STRING,C1000000161:STRING,C1000000162:NUMERIC,C1000000163:NUMERIC,C1000000164:NUMERIC,C1000000169:NUMERIC,C1000000188:STRING,C1000000215:NUMERIC,C1000000217:STRING,C1000000218:STRING,C1000000239:STRING,C1000000251:STRING,C1000000296:NUMERIC,C1000000298:STRING,C1000000300:STRING,C1000000342:STRING,C1000000396:STRING,C1000000422:STRING,C1000000426:STRING,C1000000427:STRING,C1000000541:STRING,C1000000557:NUMERIC,C1000000558:NUMERIC,C1000000559:NUMERIC,C1000000560:NUMERIC,C1000000561:NUMERIC,C1000000562:NUMERIC,C1000000563:NUMERIC,C1000000564:NUMERIC,C1000000565:NUMERIC,C1000000566:NUMERIC,C1000000567:NUMERIC,C1000000571:NUMERIC,C1000000572:NUMERIC,C1000000631:NUMERIC,C1000000642:NUMERIC,C1000000652:STRING,C1000000715:STRING,C1000000716:STRING,C1000000731:NUMERIC,C1000000744:STRING,C1000000745:STRING,C1000000746:STRING,C1000000854:STRING,C1000000869:NUMERIC,C1000000875:STRING,C1000000878:NUMERIC,C1000000942:STRING,C1000000964:NUMERIC,C1000000984:NUMERIC,C1000000985:NUMERIC,C1000000987:NUMERIC,C1000001025:NUMERIC,C1000001165:STRING,C1000001259:NUMERIC,C1000001288:NUMERIC,C1000001296:NUMERIC,C1000001317:NUMERIC,C1000001319:NUMERIC,C1000001445:NUMERIC,C1000001446:NUMERIC,C1000001555:NUMERIC,C1000001600:NUMERIC,C1000002488:STRING,C1000002613:NUMERIC,C1000003009:NUMERIC,C1000003302:STRING,C1000003662:STRING,C1000003663:STRING,C1000003664:STRING,C1000003752:STRING,C1000003753:NUMERIC,C1000003754:STRING,C1000003755:STRING,C1000003756:STRING,C1000003757:NUMERIC,C1000003761:NUMERIC,C1000003764:NUMERIC,C1000003765:NUMERIC,C1000003779:STRING,C1000003781:NUMERIC,C1000003888:STRING,C1000003889:STRING,C1000003890:STRING,C1000003891:STRING,C1000003892:STRING,C1000003893:STRING,C1000003894:STRING,C1000003895:STRING,C1000003896:STRING,C1000003897:STRING,C1000003898:STRING,C1000003899:NUMERIC,C1000003988:STRING,C1000005261:NUMERIC,C1000005661:NUMERIC,C1000005735:NUMERIC,C1000005736:NUMERIC,C1000005781:STRING,C1000005782:STRING,C1000005783:STRING,C1000005784:STRING,C1000005785:STRING,C1000005786:STRING,C1000005787:STRING,C1000005788:STRING,C1000005789:STRING,C1000005790:STRING,C1000005791:STRING,C1000005897:STRING,C1000005898:STRING,C1000005899:STRING,C1000005900:STRING,C1000005901:STRING,C1000005902:STRING,C1000005903:STRING,C1000005904:STRING,C1000005905:STRING,C1000005906:STRING,C1000005908:STRING,C1000005909:STRING,C1000005910:STRING,C1000005911:STRING,C303898800:NUMERIC,C303901000:NUMERIC,C303979600:NUMERIC,C1000005970:STRING,C536870913:NUMERIC,C536870916:NUMERIC,C1000005980:NUMERIC,C650000020:STRING,C650000021:STRING,C650000060:STRING,C536870914:NUMERIC,C536870915:STRING,C650000023:NUMERIC,C60903:STRING,C304302260:STRING,C304309530:STRING,C304309540:STRING,C304313170:STRING,C304379051:NUMERIC,C304379701:STRING,C304384051:NUMERIC,C304384081:STRING,C700000019:NUMERIC,C700000023:NUMERIC,C650000024:STRING,C700000988:NUMERIC,C781290302:NUMERIC,C60901:STRING,C60989:STRING,C301743800:STRING,C304384321:NUMERIC,C304401091:NUMERIC,C304404731:NUMERIC,C304405171:NUMERIC,C304405181:NUMERIC,C304409261:NUMERIC,C420050000:NUMERIC,C420050001:STRING,C420050002:STRING,C420050003:NUMERIC,C420050004:NUMERIC,C420050005:NUMERIC,C420050006:STRING,C420050008:NUMERIC,C420050100:STRING,C420050101:STRING,C420050102:NUMERIC,C420050103:STRING,C759110005:STRING,C759110004:NUMERIC,C759000017:NUMERIC,C536870919:STRING,C800001001:STRING,C800001012:STRING,C800001025:NUMERIC,C536870918:NUMERIC,C536870920:NUMERIC
```

========================================================================

Error:

> Waiting on bqjob_r1f519b38e9e242d9_0000016f80889252_1 ... (1s) Current
>   status: DONE
>
> BigQuery error in load operation: Error processing job 
>   'upbeat-repeater-257414:bqjob_r1f519b38e9e242d9_0000016f80889252_1':
>
> Error while reading data, error message: CSV table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1. Please look into the errors[] collection for more details. Failure details:
>
> - gs://new007/t1851data.csv: Error while reading data, error message: CSV table references column position 317, but line starting at
>     position:0 contains only 138 columns.
> - You are loading data without specifying data format, data will be treated as CSV format by default. If this is not what you mean, please
>     specify data format by --source_format.

How can i load any csv files without any errors.please suggest me the hassle free strategy to load data.

Comment: What is your file's separator? Does this table already exists in BQ?

Comment: @rmesteves  yes , i have created table in BQ and my file separator is comma (,) as i mentioned i am importing csv file

Comment: Try putting --source_format=CSV just after the load command:  bq load --source_format=CSV [...]

Comment: @rmesteves yes i have tried this option also same error.  
Failure details:
- gs://new007/t1851data.csv: Error while reading data, error message:
CSV table references column position 317, but line starting at
position:0 contains only 138 columns.

Comment: when i use --max_bad_records it is showing errors: 1.[gs://new007/t1851data.csv] Error while reading data, error message: CSV table references column position 317, but line starting at position:0 contains only 138 columns.
2. [gs://new007/t1851data.csv] Error while reading data, error message: CSV table references column position 317, but line starting at position:948 contains only 1 columns.

Comment: I think I know what is happening. I'll write an answer

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are experiencing seems to be an issue in the CSV file format, perhaps your CSV file has characters such as new line `\n` or carriage character `\r`, so then, the interpretation of the file is not correct, and this makes sense with the error you are receiving:

```
CSV table references column position 317, but line starting at position:0 
contains only 138 columns
```

Where it is saying that the first line of your CSV has only 138 columns and you are indicating 317 columns. Therefore, you will need to handle your CSV file first, removing this kind of characters that can confuse the interpreter and then try running the command again.